# Changing password in multiple boxes using script

Tags: scripting, password, ldap

I'm working in a environment which has around 400 AIX boxes. I don't have root access and I'm a normal user. The environment has no LDAP kind of centralized mechanism for authentication so the passwords are maintained in `/etc/shadow` file only.

The security policy makes us change passwords every 30 days which creates a big complication where we can't change passwords on all boxes every month, which leads us to have different passwords on each box. It's a big headache to maintain the passwords.

Is there a way to write a script which will login and change passwords in a list of the boxes so that we can change the password every month on all the boxes so that we will have the same passwords?

Answer (score 3):

#### pssh

One approach would be to use a command like `pssh` to run ssh in parallel across multiple systems at the same time.

- [original pssh website](http://www.theether.org/pssh/)
- [new pssh website](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/)

A command like this would suffice:

```
$ pssh -h ~/pssh-hosts 'printf "%s\n" old_pass new_pass new_pass | passwd'
```

This will run the command:

```
printf "%s\n" old_pass new_pass new_pass | passwd
```

which will "change" the password. The `pssh` command:

```
$ pssh -h ~/pssh-hosts '... commmands to run ...'
```

will run this command across the list of hosts in the file `~/pssh-hosts` in parallel all at the same time.

There are some examples of `pssh` in action in this tutorial titled: [pssh HOWTO](http://www.theether.org/pssh/docs/0.2.3/pssh-HOWTO.html). The `pssh` command also has other commands such as `pscp` for copying files in parallel across multiple systems.

#### sshpt (SSH Power Tool)

In the same vain as `pssh`, there's [`sshpt`](https://code.google.com/p/sshpt/). Works similar to `pssh` but is another option.

#### other options?

There are a whole slew of options beyond these two. You can see more of them listed in this ServerFault Q&A titled: [What is a good modern parallel SSH tool?](https://serverfault.com/questions/17931/what-is-a-good-modern-parallel-ssh-tool).

#### References

- [PSSH : Parallel SSH to execute commands on a number of hosts](http://zaman4linux.blogspot.com/2012/09/pssh-parallel-ssh-to-execute-commands.html)
- [pssh man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pssh/)

Comment: just a note, your solution of using pssh is very helpful, but your sample code is even more helpful.  It would be nice if your printf & pipe usage could be explained.  I admit I don't quite understand it (but it works!).