# how to add line in a /etc/sudoers file with using shell script (50servers)?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, rhel

I want to know script which can edit `/etc/sudoers` file and let me add `{{{{{userid ALL=(root) ALL}}}}` to 50 server I have on same network?

Comment: Consider a real config management system such as `puppet` or `chef`

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this Q&A on U&L where I answered a similar question. The Q was titled: [Changing password in multiple boxes using script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83571/changing-password-in-multiple-boxes-using-script).

There are 2 tools which you could use to do this. They're called `pssh` and `sshpt`.

- [original pssh website](http://www.theether.org/pssh/)
- [new pssh website](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/)
- [pssh HOWTO](http://www.theether.org/pssh/docs/0.2.3/pssh-HOWTO.html)
- [sshpt website](https://code.google.com/p/sshpt/)

#### Example

Using `pssh` you could construct a command that would append the following line to your `/etc/sudoers` files on the various hosts:

```
$ pssh -h ~/pssh-hosts 'echo "{{{{{userid ALL=(root) ALL}}}}" >> /etc/sudoers'
```

There are other ways this is just to get your started!

Comment: This is good, though, just to avoid any possible portability complications (if there are any, in this case) that could surround the use of *`echo`, `printf`* might be a better tool to  recommend. I'm not certain there would be, but I am *uncertain,* and 50 *`/etc/sudoers`* issues wouldn't be the way I'd like to learn...

Answer (score -2):

In the time it takes you to write the question, read the answers, write the script, test it, and then run it, you could have done 50 severs at 1 server every 5 minutes.

However,

1. For long term delivery of this and other requirements, use a config management system as suggested by [jordanm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13796/jordanm) such as [`puppet`](https://puppetlabs.com/) or [`chef`](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home).
2. Be very, very cautious about making changes to /etc/sudoers through a script, because if you get it wrong, you can only fix it with direct access to root.

Comment: I am not good with scripting, actually I wanna know like how we can run a single command with the help of script on all boxes...or edit a particular file.

Comment: For something like this, I usually prefer to drop a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` (using puppet, for instance), which may not be available in your version of RHEL. But for your use case, you can also use something like `tmux` or `clusterssh` to connect to many different computers and perform the same commands (the practicality of that depends on how you connect to the servers).