# Running commands on multiple servers

Tags: shell-script, remote-management

I want to execute a process on multiple servers. I am using the following wrapper script.  The script moves to servers one at a time.  I would like to change it so it can execute on multiple servers. Is there way to do it?

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(<ALL_SERVERS_IP); do
    # Tell the remote server to start bash, but since its
    # standard input is not a TTY it will start bash in
    # noninteractive mode.
    ssh -q "$ip" bash <<-'EOF'
        printf "%s\n" ================== "$(hostname) ::: Current date : $(date)" \
                            ==================
        ./remote 
    EOF
done
```

Comment: There are a bunch of options.  This blog lists 10: http://blog.crdlo.com/2010/07/parallel-ssh-tool-roundup.html

Comment: related:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83571/changing-password-in-multiple-boxes-using-script/83583#83583 & http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84936/how-to-add-line-in-a-etc-sudoers-file-with-the-help-of-shell-script-50servers/84943#84943

Comment: These are related too: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/automatically-run-commands-over-ssh-on-many-servers/19009#19009 & http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3239/how-can-i-reproduce-commands-run-on-one-machine-on-another-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know some tools for that, but the easiest is [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). Take a look and tell me what do you think.

Comment: All anwsers are useful but I can choose one solution.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome man. I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Try `pdsh`, which will execute a command on multiple remote hosts simultaneously.  Your task could be written like so:

```
pdsh -w ssh:$(echo $(<ALL_SERVERS) | sed -e 's/ /,/g') 'printf "%s\n" ...'
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). That's pretty much exactly what it was written for. In your case, you would do:

```
parallel ./remote --sshloginfile ALL_SERVERS_IP
```

The above assumes that `ALL_SERVERS_IP` is a text file with one IP or hostname per line. If they can have different logins, make the list like so:

```
user@server.example.com
foo@server2.example.com
bar@server3.example.com
```

Comment: I checked on the central server and couldn't find parallel on it.

Comment: @user67186 you only need to install it on your machine, the one you will launch the job from.

Comment: Use a bash function to give the 'printf/hostname' stuff to run. Then use `--env` to export that function to the remote server: `parallel --env myfunc --slf ALL_SERVERS_IP --nonall myfunc`

Comment: @terdon How do you have to install parallel? Can't find anything useful.

Comment: @Jenson see the link in my answer. Most Linux distributions (probably all) will have it in their repositories as `parallel`. For others, the link provides download packages.